# How to share audio files in Android Studio (Kotlin)?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

How can I share an audio file in Android Studio? I have tried the following so far, but it doesn't work.

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(OnLongClickListener {

            val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            var path = "absolute/path"
            var uri = Uri.parse(path)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            type = "audio/mp3"
        }
        startActivity(sendIntent)
        true   
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems fine, but I'd suggest you to try this one:

```
   String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
           + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.ogg"; //This is the path of your audio file
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath); //Identifier of the audio file (Uniform Resource Identifier)
   Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); //Create a new action_send intent
   share.setType("audio/*"); //What kind of file the intent gets 
   share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); //Pass the audio file to the intent
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File")); //Start the intent
```

If that doesn't work either, make sure that you granted the right permissions in the Manifest.xml file (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Indeed I forgot to grant the right permissions in the Manifest.xml. But after adding it it still just won't work.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the implementation of the setOnLongClickListener()?

Comment: The listener works, other types of sharing (like text) also work just fine. I'm pretty certain it is because of the path. It's somehow not correct.

Comment: Maybe you dont have the right permissions to the directory in which the audio is. What is the problem? It crashes? Does nothing?

Comment: The sharing options appear correctly but the audio file is just not attached. I set the right permissions by adding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Manifest.xml, I guess. So really don't know what's the issue right now. Will give an update when I figured it out though.

Comment: Would u like to post the Manifest file?

Comment: Also, try passing the intent putExtra directly the path, without parsing it to URI. delete `Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);`
and replace `share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, sharePath);`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into how to use a [file provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider). You'll find that you won't be able to provide the uri of the file directly as you're only allowed to expose its content uri. Have a look at the **Generating the Content URI for a File** section

Comment: This helped a lot! Now there is one thing I don't get: I can't find the mp3s using a file manager. So they are probably hidden. What path do I have to use now to reach them?

Comment: How are you adding these mp3 files?

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me

- Call this method onClick Button:

  ```
  fun shareAudioFile(audioFile: File) {
         val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext,
                  "com.app.package.fileprovider",
                   File(audioFile)

         val shareIntent: Intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this@MainActivity)
                  .setType("audio/mp3")
                  .setStream(uri)
                  .intent

         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Sound File"))
    }
  ```

I replaced **Uri.parse** with **FileProvider.getUriForFile**.

Replace **com.app.package** with your package.

- Add on Android Manifest:

  ```
   <application ...>
   ...
  <provider
      android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">

   <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
   </provider>

  <application/>
  ```

**applicationId** is your package

- Create **file_paths.xml** file into **xml** folder

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <external-path
           name="external_files"
           path="." />
  </paths>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Share Any File as below ( Kotlin ) :**
first create a folder named *`xml`* in the *`res`* folder and create a new XML Resource File named *`provider_paths.xml`* and put the below code inside it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="."/>

    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

now go to the *`manifests`* folder and open the *`AndroidManifest.xml`* and then put the below code inside the `<application>` tag :

```
<provider
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" /> // provider_paths.xml file path in this example
</provider>
```

now you put the below code in the `setOnLongClickListener` :

```
button.setOnLongClickListener {
    try {
        val file = File("pathOfFile")
        if(file.exists()) {
            val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.setType("*/*")
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        toast("Error")
    }
}
```